# Merge files by wildcard recursively to create a report (batch)

Tags: batch-file, merge, report

I want to traverse all subdirectories in the directory given, and write the contents of each file(as well as the filepaths) into a single report file.

Example:

```
File tree:
c:\root_dir:
dull_file.txt
subdir
relevant_file.txt

c:\root_dir\subdir:
really_relevant_file.txt
also_relevant_file.dat
```

Input:

```
C:\> make_report.bat c:\root_dir *relevant*
```

Output when writing `C:\root_dir> type report.txt:`

```
c:\root_dir\relevant_file.txt
<file contents here>
c:\root_dir\subdir\really_relevant_file.txt
<file contents here>
c:\root_dir\subdir\also_relevant_file.dat
<file contents here>
```

So far I've managed to list all the files recursively:

```
dir /s /b /a-d *.txt > file_names.txt
```

Next, I would need for each line in file_names.txt, to write its path into report.txt and to `type filepath > report.txt`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `for /r "path\to\directory" %%I in (*)` to loop through all files and directories recursively starting at `path\to\directory`.  Echo the fully qualified path, and type the file contents.  Redirect all output into `report.txt`.

```
@echo off
>report.txt (
    (
        for /r "%~1" %%I in (%2) do (
            echo %%~fI
            type "%%~fI"
        )
    )
)
```

In a console window, type `for /?` for more info on `for /r`.

Comment: That's a great start! Now I just need to filter the file names according to the wildcard.